# To get the number of counts from database using php

Tags: php

In my database a table contains different values such as

```
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,16,16,16 .
```

I need to get the count of each digits using PHP codes.

For example count of'2'=8 and count of'16' =3 so on.

I already tried the count function but it has not worked.

Comment: I think you need to post more details about the structure of your database table. I'm assuming it's a SQL table?

Comment: Where is your database file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the row from the database, now I assume you can do this, then, use

```
$store = explode(',', $row['column']; //explode the values, creates array

$fetch_dups = array_count_values($store); //duplicates

$get_count = count($fetch_dups); //returns count for each Value

print_r($get_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT column_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table_name GROUP BY column_name;`

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT
    DISTINCT column_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE column_name = tn.column_name) AS cnt
 FROM table_name tn;
```

This outputs

```
column_name | cnt
2           | 8
16          | 3
```